# Script for automatic gateway switching

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have two network connections. If one goes down other should come up automatically how i can do it with a shell script in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: If it's wireless connection, you don't need to set up anything. By default network-manager will automatically connect to whatever saved connection is nearby.

Comment: @Serg it's a wired connection

Comment: OK, and you have two ethernet ports for that, correct ? If that's the case, you could probably have a script that will do something like `while ( eth1 has address ); do no-op ; done ;  ip route add default via 192.168.0.1` . Rough pseudo-code . But probably that could work.   I haven't played with  `ip route` that much so probably someone else could write the actual code. But that's the general idea

Comment: [this](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Advanced_Routing_Failover_without_Scripting) might help you.

Comment: @Serg I don't have two Ethernet ports for that default ip ends in 2 and the backup ip ends in 47.

Comment: Ah, in that case . . . let me sketch something out . . . brb

Comment: How's this ? http://paste.ubuntu.com/19342030/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Bonding interface. Bonding interface allows you to add interfaces into bond, set one interface as primary and configure them as active-backup.

First install *ifenslave* package, stop networking and load bonding kernel module:

```
sudo apt-get install ifenslave
sudo stop networking
sudo modprobe bonding
```

Update interface configuration in file */etc/network/interfaces*:

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
  bond-slaves none
  bond-mode active-backup
  bond-miimon 100

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
  bond-master bond0
  bond-primary eth0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
  bond-master bond0
```

This creates bonding interface *bond0* set as active-backup and configures interfaces eth0 and eth1 as slaves to bond0. *Bond-primary* tag configures eth0 as primary interface and leaves eth1 as backup.

Then restart networking:

```
sudo start networking
```

You can look also to this tutorial about bonding in Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding

And for more information about bonding interfaces look here https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt